# Find names from 2 lists python using for loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, if-statement

**Hello**

I want to make a **for loop** that adds classes into a list when the class requirements are met until the max_credit is hit. `class_list` lists all the classes with their credits, co-requisite classes, required classes, and the last cell is open because I want to use it for later.

```
class_list = [['ï»¿MA 241 ', '4', '', '', ''], ['PS 150 ', '3', 'MA 241 ', '', ''], ['UNIV 101', '1', '', '', ''], ['COM 122', '3', '', '', ''], ['MA 242', '4', '', 'MA 241 ', ''],  ['PS 160', '3', 'MA 242', 'PS 150 ', '']]
class_done = ['UNIV 101', 'MA 241', [], [], [], [], [], []]
classes_for_semester=[]
credits_for_semester=0
max_credit_allowed=16
```

Now I want to add the class to the `classes_for_semester` if either the co-requisite class is in the `classes_for_semester` or the required class is in `class_done`.

I was thinking this would work, but it doesn't seem to get into the second If statement:

```
for i in range(len(class_list)):
    if int(class_list[i][1])+credits_for_semester < max_credit_allowed:
        if class_list[i][3] == '' or class_list[i][3] in class_done or class_list[i][2] in classes_for_semester:
            print(class_list[i][0])
            classes_for_semester.append(class_list[i][0])
            credits_for_semester += int(class_list[i][1])
            print(True)
```

Maybe you could help me figure out what I am doing wrong.
If you are going to post a solution that would be great but please give an explanation :), because as you can probably tell I am quite new at this and I want to understand it.

Much appreciated

Comment: When I copy your code into my ide, and change max_credit_allowed to max_credit on line 2, it seems to work. What exact problem are you facing? Is max_credit_allowed == max_credit or am I mixing up an unknown variable? Another thing to add, you may want to break the loop if credits_for_semester >= max_credit_allowed as any further iterations over the list would be pointless.

Comment: Nope you are right I must've accidentally fixed when posting this question. Thanks a lot for your suggestion though!

Comment: Does everything work for you now? Or is there still an issue?

Comment: Yeah it seems to work, but I have run into another issue, it tells me this:     if int(class_list[i][1]) + credits_for_semester < max_credit_allowed:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: but I tested it, the index gets to 43 and that's the number of rows so it should be correct and leave the for loop but it ends with the error.

Comment: If you have 43 rows in your list, the indexes range from 0 to 42. Is your "i" going to 42, or 43?

Comment: I think I know what it is. when the if statement finds a class that can be added, it removes that class from the list, but the for loop still goes with the original length. In my example, the list starts with 48 rows then finds classes removes those rows, in order to avoid taking them again and then ends with 43 rows where the error comes up.

Comment: Maybe I have to check in the if statement if that class was already used instead of removing it from the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help btw I really appreciate it!!!!

Comment: Good job debugging it. Another option is instead of using a for loop, you can use a while loop. That way in the same condition you can check if credits_for_semester >= max_credit_allowed and if i (your counter) < len(class_list). The len(class_list) should update every time the while condition is checked